# Setup Velocity in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, installation, velocity

I need to work in velocity, I read the getting started sections from velocity.apache.org but it doesn't explain how I should install, set it up.
I've installed the Velocity UI from eclipse's update manager. And then I copied the velocity-1.7.jar and velocity-1.7-dep.jar in java/lib/ext and included them in the jre6 (standard VM) at Preferences/Java/Installed JRE's.(don't really know if this is correct).
I made a dynamic web project, and in it tried a example class vrom the velocity 1.7 folder, but it doesn't work, has no errors but it doesn't recognize the resources.
What do I have to do with the template, where in the projects folder do I have to put it.
And do I have to do something else to set Velocity up?
Thanks in advance for helping a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a web project you should place the jars in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
for further information about the WAR packaging see [Web Modules in JEE5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)

In eclipse you need to add them the class-path by

> Right-click on project, Select Properties, Java-Build-Path, Tab
>   libraries, Add JARS.

Placing dependend jars in $JAVA_HOME/lib/ext isn't recommended.

Comment: ok, at properties/libraries i've added the 2 jars: velocity-1.7.jar and velocity-1.7-dep.jar at propertries/order and exports i've checked everything and still get the error: "The requested resource () is not available." I have the class "Example.java", which i copied from the velocity examples folder.
File: http://www.2shared.com/file/biWPXRp8/Example.html

Comment: Another question. where do i have to put the velocity.properties and example.vm files? into the WebContent/WEB-INF ?

Comment: @rosualin You need to add the jars under "libraries" not "order and exports"

Comment: @rosualin The property files should be located in WEB-INF/classes. BTW The example has a main method which makes no sense in a webapp. The code should be in a servlet.

Comment: yes, in libraries, i clicked on add external jars and then added the 2 jar files. only after that in order and exports i checked everything. ok, im gonna put it in a servlet, and the property file into WEB-INF/classes and gonna try after, thanks a lot

Comment: 10x a lot, made it somehow to work, and now I'm starting to understand how velocity works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the [developer guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html), you can getting start by this guide.

Comment: yeah, i read it, but it says something about downloading velocity, which i did , and then directly about how it works, how to initialize the velocity engine. and i don't really know the steps that are in between downloading and well writing code. I downloaded the velocity 1.7 zip, extracted it, but do i have to put in somewhere, or what should i do with it?

Comment: i agree. the guide may be good in explaining how velocity works but there isn't any good information how to get velocity to run in the eclipse ide in the first place.